# Как работать со множеством свойств в модели?

Tags: laravel

Не совсем обычный проект мне достался, сильно завязан на дизайне. Т.е. пользователи могут самостоятельно например к заголовку новости применить некоторые стили(тень, цвет тени, отступы и тд). Все эти свойства должны храниться в бд.

Пока насчитал порядка 150 свойств, соответственно +150 полей в таблицу бд ну как то глаза режет) Да и в методе куча полей типа `'text_font' => $request->text_font`

Как вариант можно использовать контейнер свойств и все хранить в джисоне в одном поле бд, но тогда придется кучу кода переписать.

Как поступить? Продолжить создавать поля в бд 151,152,153...n или все в одном поле хранить?

Comment: Создание кучи полей выглядит как лютый костыль с учетом, что это всего лишь свойства стилей. Лучше всё же json.

Comment: Т.е если Вам точно не надо никак агрегировать эти данные (допустим, искать, сколько пользователей использует жирный шрифт) – точно не надо.